# Document ready start one function but not the other function unify

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have a strange situation that my $(document).ready(function(){ script is loaded for my usernamecheck and emailcheck but also not for my [Unify 2.1](https://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v2.1/) script.

In the following example you see both script were after 2 days searching I still haven't found anything and I run out of clues

Working example: https://gitaartabs.nl/templates2/unify-main/shortcodes/promo/gitaartabs-backup.php
But at my homepage with other menu's it isn't: https://www.gitaartabs.nl/homev41

Hope s.o. can help. 
Jan

```
$javascripts = array("
$(document).ready(function(){

        // initialization of carousel
        $.HSCore.components.HSCarousel.init('.js-carousel');

         // initialization of carousel e-book
        $('#carousel3').slick('setOption', 'dots', true, true);
        $('#carousel3').slick('setOption', 'dotsClass', 'js-pagination u-carousel-indicators-v30 g-pos-abs g-top-0', true);
        $('#carousel3').slick('setOption', 'customPaging', function (slider, i) {
          var title = $(slider.).data('title');

          return '<i class="u-dot-line-v2 g-brd-gray-light-v2--before g-brd-gray-light-v2--after g-mb-15--sm"><span class="u-dot-line-v2__inner g-bg-white--before g-brd-3--before--active g-brd-gray-light-v2--before g-brd-primary--before--active g-transition--ease-in g-transition-0_2"></span></i><span class="hidden-sm-down g-color-black g-font-size-15">' + title + '</span>';
        }, true);


      $(window).on('load', function () {
        // initialization of header
        $.HSCore.components.HSHeader.init($('#js-header'));
        $.HSCore.helpers.HSHamburgers.init('.hamburger');

        // initialization of HSMegaMenu component
        $('.js-mega-menu').HSMegaMenu({
          event: 'hover',
          pageContainer: $('.container'),
          breakpoint: 991
        });
");
```

Updates: I use php and my index.php use the script below.

```
//include javascripts array()
if(count($javascripts) > 0) {
    foreach($javascripts as $javascript) {
        echo "\n\t<script>".$javascript."</script>"; 
    }
}
```

Perhaps I need to backslash the **$slides[i]** ? within this code?

```
  var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');
```

Comment: Check the error console, you have a parser error in line 2302

Comment: Thanks, I did see this one, but have no idea how to solve this parser error >Parser as "something unexpected" [described on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: It probably get more weird. I also asked support from htmlstream and they set up a test were it seems to work without a problem but when i compare my code with the test (https://gitaartabs.nl/view/test.html) I see no different.

Comment: on your home page 'var title = $(slider.).data('title'); ', line 2328 - causes the error - the dot inside the bracket causes the error. Your other page example contains another syntax: 'var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');' this one is correct.

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem from the include ? I just updated the question with the include function I use at my index.php

Answer (score 0):

Looking long for the problem but just forgot }); in the end thanx @axel.michel

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above. The homepage has a parser error, consult the error console, and you can see the reason why. The inline JS-Code in your homepage contains the following line:

```
var title = $(slider.).data('title');
```

This causes the error. The dot behind the slider is not allowed here. If you write a dot here, it awaits a following property name of the given slider variable. In your other page examples the same line contains a different syntax:

```
var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');
```

This one is valid JS, and will not cause a parse error.